# Using ArcMap georeferencing link file with in GDAL or another alternative?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, georeferencing

I've a lot of georeferencing link files from ArcMap 10 that are like so:

```
 5.693887   17.605231   37.000000   -17.000000
 5.896141   5.922077    37.000000   -19.000000     
 16.877354  5.957769    39.000000   -19.000000
 27.882361  5.862591    41.000000   -19.000000
 27.977539  17.545744   41.000000   -17.000000
 16.823816  17.617128   39.000000   -17.000000
 16.800021  23.439669   39.000000   -16.000000
```

The first two are the X and Y in inches of the source image and the second are the map X and map Y (lon lat in degrees)

I'd rather not use ArcMap to transform them, and neither would I like to translate the inches into pixels using calculations are there are a rather lot of maps, from differing sources and each may have a different resolution.

If there is no better way I will check the resolutions then just adjust the Inches by the resolution, i.e at 400 ppi the  5.693887" is at pixel X 2,278.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageMagick can report 'Resolution' i.e.

```
identify -verbose ./TIFFS*.tif | grep -B5 Resolution
```

(-B5 as Resolution is on the 5th line)

But following comments about `gdal_info` I iterate all the tiffs in a folder and then create a .x-res file per tiff that I can use later in the process:

```
gdalinfo $filename".tif" | grep TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION | grep -m 1 -e "[0-9]*" -o > $filename".x-res";
```

Then I can iterate the ArcMap georeferencing link files (the link filename relates to the source tiff) read the various elements i.e. source_inch_x/y  and read in the .x-res for the current link file to calculate the pixel X, Y.

```
xres=$(<../Geo-referenced-tiffs/$filename.x-res)
source_pixel_x=$(echo "scale = 2; $source_inch_x*$xres"|bc)
```

Comment: You can find the resolution with gdalinfo if those tifftags are set. Example output `Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=254
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=254` Then you know the resolution and inches and you can convert values into GCP pixels and lines for gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks, I'll work up a script using gdalinfo, goal_translate/warp and update the answer.